# static variables and local

Tags: c, static

The output is : 100 -10 0 100 -5 2 10. Why? 
After running the first time b() the static x at the end of b() is -5 (I check) so why c() gave 0, isn't it use static x?

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int x;
void a()
{
    int x=100;
    printf("% d ",x);
    x+=5;
}
void b()
{
    static int x=-10;
    printf("%d ",x);
    x+=5;

}
void c()
{

    printf("%d ",x);
    x+=2;
}
int main()
{
    int x=10;
    a();
    b();
    c();
    a();
    b();
    c();
    printf("%d ",x); 
    return 0;
}
int x=0;
```

Comment: Where is the `static x`?

Comment: `static` and `extern` are 2 different things

Comment: You have four different variables (with varying scope) all named `x`.

Comment: Who came to the first use of c()?

Comment: `printf("% d ",x);` is a mistake

Comment: Your root mistake is shadowing variables. Don't do that. Consider enabling warnings about it (`-Wshadow` for *gcc* and probaby for *clang* too), though on 2nd thought it probably won't help with globals vs. function scope statics, but you could still try it out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
void c()
{

    printf("%d ",x);
    x+=2;
}
```

It will not use static copy of x which you allocated in defination function `b()`.

It will use the global copy of variable x which you have declared in last line of your program.

```
int x=0;
```

Change last line of x to different value and output will be changed for `c()`

---

**Why a global one and not a static?**

So here in scope of that static variable x is limited to body of `b()` only so in c() it can not be used.

c() is depending on global copy of x. If you remove that global definition of x then in C() it will give compilation error.

Comment: Why a global one and not a static? Doesn't static is the dominant?

Comment: @dan names declared in a scope are only visible within that scope. `static int x;` inside `b()` is only visible within `b()`.  `x` used outside of `b` must refer to a different variable than `b`'s `x`.

Comment: @dan updated my answer to address your question in comment

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand about variable scope.

Variable `x` in `a()` differs with `x` in `b()` and differs with the global `x` (out of these function)

They have same name `x` ,but they take difference locator in memory.

Just read about local and global variable in C you will figure out the problem.